# How to create custom urls in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, url-routing

I have created a cakephp app. I have urls looks like

```
www.mysite.com/products/search/hardware
```

It loads fine. But I want urls that looks like

```
www.mysite.com/hardware
```

Can this is achieved by setting route connect

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a route.

```
Router::connect(
    '/hardware',
    array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'search', 'hardware')
);
```

For a more general solution (any category name routing to products/search) see http://book.cakephp.org/view/948/Defining-Routes

Answer (score 1):

You could add something like

```
 Router::connect('/hardware',
                  array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'search'),
                  array('pass' => array('search'), 'search' => 'hardware'));
```

in your routes.php file, but then you would have to do it for each searchable item.

The problem you will be facing if you want something automatic, is that you need a way to differentiate your searchable products from every other model you have. So maybe you should settle for another type of URL like

```
 www.mysite.com/products/hardware
```

or

```
 www.mysite.com/s/hardware
```

and use the appropriate routes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating hardware_controller in your controllers folder.

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that but I also have other categories, so I would have to create lot more controllers. Thought their could simpler solution.

Comment: Never really understood how the router works tbh I find it a bit confusing so I tend to avoid it. Sorry.